# Can I replace single-rank memory with dual rank memory?

Tags: memory

I have a laptop configuration as follows:

HP Pavilion Gaming - 15-ec1008ca

2 slots:  4 GB DDR4-3200 CL22 on each slot   (total 8 GB)

I first considered buying a single 16 GB  DDR4-3200 CL22 stick and replacing one of the 4 GB sticks. Incidentally, would that be a very bad idea? Some said yes, some said no.

The other option is to spend a bit more and get a 2x16 kit (32 GB total).  Crucial recommended this upon scanning my laptop:

https://www.amazon.ca/Crucial-16GBx2-PC4-25600-Unbuffered-260-Pin/dp/B07Q7T9NSC/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=CT2K16G4SFD832A&qid=1634292693&sr=8-3&th=1

Which is a 2x16 kit but the reason I'm worried  is that it's labelled as "dual rank" on Crucial's website and my current RAM is "single rank".  Will me replacing the single rank with dual rank yield harmful/negative effects?

Thank you!

Comment: What does HP say is the maximum amount of memory you can have?

Answer (score 0):

The Crucial scanner is never wrong (in my experience), so you may trust
its results.

You may buy directly from Crucial, as they guarantee their scan.

Amazon also has a money-back guarantee, so you don't risk much
(just ensure that this is truly the same RAM as recommended by the
Crucial scanner.)